# Put resource on classpath at runtime

Tags: java, osgi

I need to create an instance of org.apache.camel.guice.Main in my application. For reasons I don't want to get into, I cannot package a jndi.properties file in my jar/bundle, which will be used by org.apache.camel.guice.Main.run() to bootstrap the app. I also cannot write anything to the file system.

I do have the properties that would normally go into jndi.properties available at runtime as a java object, map of strings, whatver. Can I write these out to a "dynamic" jndi.properties and put it on the classpath (or add it to a classloader as a "resource")? Something like:

```
this.getClass().putResourceAsStream(properties);
```

So that 3rd party frameworks that do need to load via getResource() or getResourceAsStream() can do it?

Comment: Does the Jndi implementation you use, provide any other way to populate with values?

Comment: Maybe yes, you gave me an idea, let me try somethign

Comment: What is your runtime environment? In some environments, your App class loader is a URL class loader and you can use reflection to add an extra URL. If you use bnd launcher, there are many possible solutions.

Comment: Orcale jre, runtime is karaf 4.2.+ , normal java classloader from thread context can use urls, but i was averse to using reflection because i dont want to violate any security constraints, if you know of a clean way to do it post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing 4 things:

1. Using the constructor in InitialContext that takes
   java.util.Properties as an argument to create the context
2. Using a hack in Activator to make sure my application bundle is using bundle context classloader, not the thread context classloader
3. Use require bundle in addition to package-imports in the header.
4. Using org.apache.camel.guice.Main.run() to start camel

Big thanks to Thorbjorn Andersen in the comments, that made me go back and take a closer look at the InitialContext api.